# Opengl: control object move speed and time

Tags: c++, opengl, animation

I am trying to make a little animation(2D) with it. My initial setting is:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Hence it is basically a 2D scene. I have some polygons in the scene. For each of the polygons, it has properties like x_pos, x_speed, y_pos and y_speed. What I want are two things:

1. move the polygons according to their x and y speed;
2. movethe polygons for a certain duration of time (say 1 second), and than change the speed of the polygon by calling other functions.

What I can do now is to make the polygon move. But not as the exact speed that I set. For example, if a polygon is at position (20, 20), and it moves alone the x-axis to the position (40, 20), with x_speed = 10. Then I want is that this is done in exact 2 seconds. When it reaches (40, 20), it stops, or move with another speed.

What are the best way to achieve these?

Comment: "What I can do now is to make the polygon move."...how?

Comment: So you're simulating a physics engine. Usually this is done by measuring the amount of time that has passed since things were last updated, and then only updating according to how much time has passed instead of using a static frame-by-frame value. (This is a basic way, not the best or even most modern)

Comment: @genpfault I used glTranslatef(this->x_pos, this->y_pos, 0.0) before creating the polygon, and if I want it to move, I use this->x_pos += this->x_speed; and glutPostRedisplay();